# why the interpreter tell me "This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'"

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I write a ocaml program that parse an arithmetic expression by parser combinator.

```
type 'a parser = char list -> ('a * (char list)) list
let return (x: 'a): 'a parser = fun input -> [x, input]
let fail: 'a parser = fun _ -> []
let ( >>= ) (p: 'a parser) (f : 'a -> 'b parser): 'b parser =
    fun input -> List.map (fun (x, i) -> f x i) (p input) |> List.flatten

let ( ||| ) (p: 'a parser) (q: 'a parser) = 
    fun input -> (p input) @ (q input)

let token: (char parser) = function
    | x::xs -> [x, xs]
    | [] -> []

let char(c: char): (char parser) =
    token >>= fun x ->
    if x = c then return x else fail

let digit: (char parser) =
    token >>= fun x ->
    if x >= '0' && x <= '9' then return x else fail

let rec many(p: 'a parser): 'a list parser =
    (p >>= fun x ->
    many p >>= fun xs ->
    (return (x::xs))) 
    ||| (return [])

let number = 
    many digit >>= fun x -> 
    return (List.fold_left (fun l r -> l * 10 + (int_of_char r - int_of_char '0')) 0 x)

type expr = Add of (expr * expr)
            | Sub of (expr * expr)
            | Mul of (expr * expr)
            | Div of (expr * expr)
            | Neg of expr
```

The code above works well.

```
let rec expression: expr parser =
    term >>= fun l ->
    (char '+' ||| char '-') >>= fun op ->
    term >>= fun r ->
    if op = '+' then return (Add (l, r)) else return (Sub (l, r))
and term: expr parser =
    factor >>= fun l ->
    (char '*' ||| char '/') >>= fun op ->
    factor >>= fun r ->
    if op = '*' then return (Mul (l, r)) else return (Div (l, r))
and factor: expr parser =
    expression
    ||| (char '(' >>= fun _ ->
        expression >>= fun e ->
        char ')' >>= fun _ ->
        return e)
    ||| (char '-' >>= fun _ ->
        factor >>= fun e -> 
        return (Neg e))
```

But there is an error in this piece of code

```
    Error: This kind of expression is not allowed as right-hand side of `let rec'
```

This page([link](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/imperative-programming-1.html)) says:
"the compiler only allows three possible constructs to show up on the righthand side of a let rec: a function definition, a constructor, or the lazy keyword."

I think type parser is a function instead of a value, why this happened?

Comment: Did your compiler tell you your error line ?

Comment: Characters 37-178:
  ..term >>= fun l ->
                (char '+' ||| char '-') >>= fun op ->
                term >>= fun r ->
                if op = '+' then return (Add (l, r)) else return (Sub (l, r))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right hand side should be "function definition" not just a function. Function definition is a syntactic construct, of the [form](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec121) `fun ->` or `function ...`, including syntactic sugar for `let f x ...`.  A more correct wording is in sections [6.7.1](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#sec121) and [7.3](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#s%3Alocaldef) of the manual.

Answer (score 1):

"Function definition" means a literan `fun x ->` construct.  Functional languages consider partial function applications like

```
factor >>= fun l -> ...
```

redexes, not literal values, which means a strict language has to evaluate them immediately when they appear on the RHS of a simple variable binding, like

```
term = factor >>= fun l -> ...
```

Since, in general, eagerly evaluating the RHS of a recursive definition produces an infinite loop, strict languages generally either ban the construct or require the binding to be marked explicitly lazy.